# need help implementing InnoDB storage engine to existing database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, innodb

I am trying to add primary keys to my tables, via Sequel Pro and it said "This table currently does not support relations. Only tables that use the InnoDB storage engine support them."

I went into phpMyAdmin and looked at the storage engines and saw InnoDB listed, highlighted in blue, then I selected it and it displayed this info: http://cl.ly/68Ph

[image]

It is enabled, but I am unsure how to implement it to my existing database, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should tell your tables to use `InnoDB`:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=InnoDB
```

for existing tables,

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (…) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

for the new ones.

Note that `InnoDB` supports neither `SPATIAL` nor `FULLTEXT` indexes so don't use it if your application relies on them.

Comment: Thanks. I need to do some house-keeping, my query went from 5 seconds to 20+.